# How to become full administrator in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I want to move a file but I am getting below error. I thought that my account is not administrator but when I check accounts and users section from control panel I have found that  My account is admin. How can I move this file?

**Note:** When I right click and go to Properties-Security-Advanced tab I couln't change(even view) owner of this file. It says "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings"

```
You'll need to provide administrator permission to move this file.
```

Comment: What file are you trying to move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a quick registry hack for this.  Just Google "Take Ownership .reg".  Basically, 2 registry keys - one to add and one to remove.  You just need to double-click the .reg file to add the hack to your registry, and it'll add "Take Ownership" to your Windows Explorer menu.  Then whenever you get those errors about permission, you right click the mouse on that file or folder, and it'll allow you access to it.  Be careful about exposing certain folders to editing for security reasons.  Add the other hack, Remove Take Ownership if you want the ability to lock up that file/folder again.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following commands and replace E: with the letter of the partition you want to apply the commands or change the folder path.

**Update:**

In some cases, as happened to me, the context menu was missing some items and I could not create files in some places so I have disabled UAC by Regedit.

**Warning:**

This is not recommended, UAC is highly recommended that greater security is enabled for Windows, but as I am not a layman user as well, I leave off these screens to avoid unnecessarily requesting confirmation.

Through the run, go to regedit and navigate to the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system
```

Change the value of property `EnableLUA` from `1` to `0`

```
takeown /F "E:" /A /R /D Y
icacls "E:" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Answer (score 0):

The process that is moving the file must be started as administrator. If you are using a command line to do "move /here/file.txt /there/file.txt", then start a new shell by right-clicking on the "Command Prompt" icon and picking 'Run as administrator'. If using the Explorer to drag'n'drop, then start a new "Windows Explorer" in the same manner.